# Flutter Session (Could not get resource)

Tags: flutter, session, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

### [Solved]

I went for an older version as [jeugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14137829/jeugene) suggested to solve the below problem. The unavailable version is "0.1.1", the version I used is "0.0.7".

I keep getting the bellow error every time I try using the flutter_session package on a project. I've been wondering if there's someone out there who has had my kind of problem and can propose a solution.

> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar'. > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar'. > jcenter.bintray.com: Temporary failure in name resolution > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences' of type org.gradle.api.Project. * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 2m 10s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

My pubspec.yaml has these;

```
dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    flutter_svg: ^0.18.1
    http: ^0.12.2
    flutter_session: ^0.1.1
    geolocator: ^6.0.0
    geocoder: ^0.2.1
    headup_loading: ^1.0.3
```

and I have these is the main.dart file;

```
import 'package:flutter_session/flutter_session.dart';
```

Is there something am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the spacing of the dependencies correct. Extra space can create errors in pubspec.yaml.  Another possibility is that the specific version might not be available. Try older version of the same.

Comment: jeugene spaces are fine, I had to use an older version as you suggested and It works.